# New template in Umbraco, won't show on the Template drop down on content pages

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

Another Umbraco question, apologies.
I've created a new template in the Master templates list, but this template doesn't show up in the Templates drop down list on content pages.
I'm wondering if there's something I've missed, or if there's a way to publish this which isn't immediately obvious.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to select the template as an allowed template type for the Document Type of your pages. Lets say you're page Document Type is called "ContentPage" and you've added a new template called "NewTemplate".

By default you won't be able to select the new template when editing your "ContentPage" pages. You'll need to go into "Settings" in Umbraco, and then expand the "Document Types" folder. You'll see a list of all of the Document Types, select the one you want to use the template on ("ContentPage" in this example).

The first tab that you'll see is the "Info" tab. There's a checkbox list called "Allowed Templates" that you need to select your new template in. Save the Document Type and go back into the Content. You should now be able to select "NewTemplate" as a template on your "ContentPage" pages on the site!

Comment: Thanks again Tim! I promise I'm getting my head round Umbraco soon. :)

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate to engage in thread necromancy, but because this is the first Google result and things appear to have changed in 7.4.3 (the first version of Umbraco I've ever experienced), I'd like to share the process I use to add templates to document types.

1. Go to "Settings".
2. Expand "Document Types" and select the document type to which you'd like to apply the template.
3. Click "Templates" in the top right of the page.
4. Click "Choose extra template".
5. Select the template you wish to allow and click "Close".
6. Click "Save".
7. Go to "Content".
8. You should now be able to create new content under the document type you selected with the template you specified.

I hope that helps to save another new Umbraco dev some head-scratching.

Comment: Thank you for your Necromancy, just helped me out of a pinch. Umbraco seems to like to change around where it puts things at to confuse the noobs coming on board.